# If you are disarmed and leave the zone will your weapon be there when you return?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in labyrinthian and was disarmed, as I had never been disarmed before I just thought my Mehrunes Razor had been Unequipped I promptly pulled out chillrend and continued on to get the staff I was there for. Upon arrival at winter hold I realized it was not in my inventory  I am now crawling through labyrinthian trying to find it.

If you are disarmed, and leave the area without retrieving your weapon, will it still be there when you return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get your weapon back if you haven't waited for an in-game week. If you waited that long, then cells and interiors will reset and if that happens, you won't be able to get your weapon. if you're on PC, you could just simply use cheats to get it back. Also try to find a way in the ruins to get to the place where you last had that weapon.

Comment: Alright I persisted since it had not been an in game week and I found it in front of the word wall  thanks

Comment: @TravisMarlow since this answered your question, click on the gray check on the left below the votes and it should turn green,. This means this answer is accepted.